# Touch to expand notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am implementing a customized notification. I would like to know is it possible have the notification expand on touch of notification or click of a button?

If so how to implement?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should look into Android Animation:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/index.html

You can simply define a layout for your notification area and apply a animation transformation on it!